# Letter turns yellow after a diagonal line in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image: someone explain?! thanks]

I don't understand, the file is saved with that letter and it turns yellow, tho it only happens with some, and when it turns yellow, it ruins the code and the video doesnt pop up...

Comment: This is not a letter, this is a tabulation. Your editor is doing syntax highlighting. Add a `r` at the beginning of the string definition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Comment: basically in normal strings backslash has a special meaning to allow you to type special characters. `\t` is the tab character in this instance. in order to type a literal backslash, you either need to type the escape character first (so type a double backslash `C:\\file\\path`) or, turn off escape characters by using the "raw string" format `r"c:\file\path"`. Finally many python utilities can automatically recognize and convert forward slashes instead: `"c:/file/path"`

Comment: that is an escape sequence with a special meaning: TAB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a letter, this is a tabulation, thus the special syntax highlighting in your text editor:

```
print('abc\tdef')
```

output: `abc    def`

Use a raw string by prefixing the string with `r` to avoid interpretation of the `\t` as tabulation:

```
print(r'abc\tdef')
```

output: `abc\tdef`

Comment: Hey! thanks, a lot man! I'm moving to python and OpenCV now since I'm done with Linux so I'm kinda new and I barely know shit, I'm looking forward to exploring this area and mastering it along the way and I think it will be worth my time and it will be fun so once more, thanks, bro!